Install BIOS on Samsung NP530U3C-A09IT
In my PC the bios battery is dead. I replaced the battery but now the PC starts for a few seconds and then reboots. The F2 key has no effect on entering the BIOS. I read that this problem is caused by corrupt bios. I can't find this BIOS version anywhere and I don't know how to reinstall it. I also took the PC to SAMSUNG assistance but they don't know what to do. Can you help me?

"I read that this problem is caused by corrupt bios." - Replacing the CMOS battery wouldn't have caused the BIOS to become corrupt.  The CMOS battery essentially provides a real-time clock. I would verify the battery is installed in the correct orientation.

That sounds like it's failing POST - do any beeps sound/keyboard lights flash before it reboots? If it's failing POST, the number of beeps/keyboard flashes will tell you which hardware the issue is at. If it's not beeping/flashing the keyboard lights a specific number of times, you can usually force a BIOS flash by loading a specific BIOS file onto a USB drive, plugging the drive into a specific USB port with the laptop off, then holding down a specific key combo while powering on. OEM support site
